# can clamtk slow down ubuntu?

Tags: clamav, clamtk

can clamtk with clamav slow down my ubuntu 20.10? I have clamtk and clamav both on this computer. I've noticed it is slower and I think it may be that I have both installed. Can you only work with clamav? If this isn't the case, what would you suggest me look at? I don't see if this has been asked before.

Comment: You can just install ClamAV.... TK is just the graphical front end to it. I don't perceive any performance issues running ClamTK on my 20.04.2 LTS system. Updates are set to be done in the wee small hours when the PC is not in use anyway.

Comment: Any application you install, that runs in the background put an extra load on your system and might slow it down. If your system feels sloe, take a look at `top` (or another monitoring tool) to see what processes that is using resources. Also run `free -h` to see memory and swap usage.

Comment: how do I install top? I went and look for it in the Ubuntu software center and didn't find it.

Comment: top is already installed on a standard system. Open a terminal `Ctrl+Alt+t` and type top. [This](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) is the man page for it.